# Set SelectedValue of DropDownList inside UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, updatepanel, selectedvalue

I've got a set of cascading dropdowns, but I want the default selectedvalue to be there when when page loads though.
Right now, my dropdownlist is defaulting to the first value in the DDL.
(ASP.NET C#)

and the code (issue is with the "DDL_Assignment" dropdown)...

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <b>Position Type:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Lbl_PositionType" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="TR_Occupation" runat="server">
        <td>
            <b>Select Occupation:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_Occupation" runat="server" DataSourceID="DataSource_Occupation" DataTextField="Position" DataValueField="Position"
                AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDL_Occupation_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="DataSource_Occupation" runat="server" 
                OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetPositions" 
                TypeName="HumanResourceTableAdapters.PositionTableAdapter">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Lbl_PositionType" Name="PositionType" 
                        PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:ObjectDataSource>

            <asp:TextBox ID="TB_Occupation" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Select Assignment Name:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_Assignment" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_Assignment" runat="server"
                         AutoPostBack="True"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDL_Assignment_SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="DataSource_Assignment" runat="server" 
                        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetAssignments" 
                        TypeName="HumanResourceTableAdapters.PositionTableAdapter">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DDL_Occupation" Name="Position" 
                                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Lbl_PositionType" Name="PositionType" 
                                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="DataSource_AssignmentHourly" runat="server" 
                        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
                        SelectMethod="GetAssignmentByPosType" 
                        TypeName="HumanResourceTableAdapters.PositionTableAdapter">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Lbl_PositionType" Name="PositionType" 
                                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TB_Assignment" runat="server" />
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DDL_Occupation" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

        </td>
    </tr>
```

behind code
"posRow.Assignment" outputs the correct value... the dropdownlist just isn't taking it in for some reason

```
Position1TableAdapter position1TableAdapter =
                new Position1TableAdapter();
            HumanResource.Position1Row posRow =
                position1TableAdapter.GetData(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["PositionID"]))[0];

            DDL_Assignment.DataTextField = "AssignmentName";
            DDL_Assignment.DataValueField = "AssignmentName";
            DDL_Assignment.DataSourceID = "DataSource_Assignment";

            DDL_Occupation.SelectedValue = posRow.Position;
            DDL_Assignment.SelectedValue = posRow.Assignment;
            TB_Assignment.Text = posRow.Assignment;
            TB_Replaced.Text = posRow.Replaced;
            DDL_PositionDays.SelectedValue = posRow.PositionDays.ToString();
            DDL_ContractDays.SelectedValue = posRow.ContractDays.ToString();
            DDL_PositionHours.SelectedValue = posRow.PositionHours.ToString();
            DDL_Location.SelectedValue = posRow.Location.ToString();
            TB_Contract.Text = posRow.IsContractInformationNull() ? null : posRow.ContractInformation;
            DDL_1yrContractReason.SelectedValue = posRow.Isposition_1yrcntrctrsnIDNull() ? null : posRow.position_1yrcntrctrsnID.ToString();
            RBL_Administrator.SelectedValue = posRow.Administrator.ToString();
            RBL_CertifiedSalarySchedule.SelectedValue = posRow.clas_CertifiedScheduleInd.ToString();
            RBL_OvertimeExempt.SelectedValue = posRow.position_OvertimeExemptInd.ToString();
            RBL_ExtendedContractExempt.SelectedValue = posRow.position_ExtContractExemptInd.ToString();
            RBL_LongevityException.SelectedValue = posRow.Longevity_Exception_Indicator.ToString();
            RBL_NoStepIncrease.SelectedValue = posRow.position_NoStepInd.ToString();
            RBL_JobShare.SelectedValue = posRow.position_JobShareInd.ToString();
```

let me know if any other details are needed

Comment: Did you try setting the selected value in the DDL's DataBound event or the Page PreRender?

Comment: Can't do it in the databound event because I'm rebinding when the dropdowns are changed and after it is changed I don't want it to make that selection
Page_PreRender didn't make a difference when I tried

Comment: So you wanted that on all page load or just first one? I understood it is just for first time load of the page, and so you can check if it !IsPostBack in DataBound. It is possible that I am not misunderstanding your question.

Comment: I want it to have that selected value on page load only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed to databind before each ddl

```
Position1TableAdapter position1TableAdapter =
                new Position1TableAdapter();
            HumanResource.Position1Row posRow =
                position1TableAdapter.GetData(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["PositionID"]))[0];

            DDL_Assignment.DataTextField = "AssignmentName";
            DDL_Assignment.DataValueField = "AssignmentName";
            DDL_Assignment.DataSourceID = "DataSource_Assignment";

            DDL_Occupation.DataBind();
            DDL_Occupation.SelectedValue = posRow.Position;

            DDL_Assignment.DataBind();
            DDL_Assignment.SelectedValue = posRow.Assignment;

            TB_Replaced.Text = posRow.IsReplacedNull() ? null : posRow.Replaced;

            DDL_PositionDays.DataBind();
            DDL_PositionDays.SelectedValue = posRow.PositionDays.ToString();

            DDL_ContractDays.DataBind();
            DDL_ContractDays.SelectedValue = posRow.ContractDays.ToString();

            DDL_PositionHours.DataBind();
            DDL_PositionHours.SelectedValue = posRow.PositionHours.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your code witch is setting dropdown list selected value in the page load. when you change selected value of a dropdown list in fired event it would not set the selected value.
just call your setter method in page load event of page. you problem will be solved.

Comment: the code I posted above is under the pageload and if(!IsPostBack)

Comment: remove the !IsPostBack and tell me what happened. also try using selected index instead of selected value

Comment: taking off the !IsPostBack messes up the updatePanels and it's still defaulting to the first option in the DDL on page load check my comment to jp2code about the selectedIndex

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`DDL_Occupation.SelectedValue = posRow.Position;`

Could you need `SelectedIndex`?

```
DDL_Occupation.SelectedIndex = posRow.Position;
```

Comment: Nope. DDL_Occupation is fine, and both the Occupation and Assignment DDLs have string values, posRow.Position and posRow.Assignment both output stings correctly